# Scheduled task doesnt work Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, batch, powershell, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have this batch that makes a scheduled task calling to a powershell script and i cant make it run in windows 8. It works perfectly on windows 7 but when i use it in windows 8 it keep stuck. My problem is that the task doesn´t start, but it´s created and scheduled. When i start the powershell script without scheduling it works perfectly.

Batch:

> @copy /y wall.jpg %APPDATA%
>   @copy /y cuenta.ps1 %APPDATA%
>   schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn wallpaper /tr "powershell
>   -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File %appdata%\cuenta.ps1"

Powershell :

```
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
namespace Wallpaper
{
   public enum Style : int
   {
       Tile, Center, Stretch, NoChange
   }
   public class Setter {
      public const int SetDesktopWallpaper = 20;
      public const int UpdateIniFile = 0x01;
      public const int SendWinIniChange = 0x02;
      [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
      private static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
      public static void SetWallpaper ( string path, Wallpaper.Style style ) {
         SystemParametersInfo( SetDesktopWallpaper, 0, path, UpdateIniFile | SendWinIniChange );
         RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", true);
         switch( style )
         {
            case Style.Stretch :
               key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "2") ; 
               key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ;
               break;
            case Style.Center :
               key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "1") ; 
               key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "0") ; 
               break;
            case Style.Tile :
               key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", "1") ; 
               key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", "1") ;
               break;
            case Style.NoChange :
               break;
         }
         key.Close();
      }
   }
}
"@

[Wallpaper.Setter]::SetWallpaper( '%appdata%\wall.jpg', 0 )
```

Basically im calling to a ps1 which changes the wallpaper every x minutes. Did anyone solved a problem like this?

Comment: Does event viewer or task scheduler screen show anything as to why it didn't start? I'm not sure about powershell, but since it's built on .NET what happens if you wrap it in a Try Catch block so you can publish the exception (if there is one)?

Comment: ok, im goint to try

Comment: You'll need to do something in the catch to log it in some manner.

Comment: @Dave Well i dont know if im doing good the try catch but it doesn´t report anthing, it works perfectly when i do it directly without scheduling. Im doing like this:

 try {     
[Wallpaper.Setter]::SetWallpaper( '%appdata%\wall.jpg', 0 )  
}  
          catch [System.Net.WebException],[System.IO.IOException]{}

i dont know how to do it properly

Comment: Of course in win8 this really isn't needed, there is a property to change the wallpaper ever X minutes built in to win8.

Comment: Then see that event viewer shows